# Module not found error

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
// scripts/run.py
from src.LinksFetcher import LinksFetcher

links_fetcher = LinksFetcher()
print links_fetcher.get_urls()
```

My src folder has following structure

```
src/
  - __init__.py
  - LinksFetcher.py
```

When i try to run

```
scraper> python scripts/run.py
```

it shows error

```
ImportError: no module named src.LinksFetcher
```

Where as if i run this code inside pycharm it works fine

I am unable to identify what is wrong with it.

Comment: You have to be in the folder **above** `src` when you want to run `python scripts/run.py`.

Comment: @stovfl I have tried this also didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your folder structure looks like this -

```
sample/
      __init__.py
      src/
         __init__.py
         LinksFetcher.py

      scripts/
         run.py
```

then in **run.py** file you need to add this -

```
 import sys
 import os
 sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))
```

check if its true , else add the scripts directory structure also.

Comment: Excatly, but can you please explain your answer also so that i may have better understanding.

Comment: by default your python path does not contains your previous directory so to include your previous directory you need to add the last statement which adds __<current_path>/scripts/..__ in your system path and python will be able to find src module from the path added above. please mark this answer as completed if you like it .

Comment: Got it, but it seems not a good approach to me. Should i change my directory structure ?

Answer (score 1):

Does your `folder structure` looks like the following:

```
scripts/
    run.py
    src/
        __init__.py
        LinksFetcher.py
```

Add this to your code, may I see the **first** string from the list:

```
print('sys.path={}'.format(sys.path))
```